# I need to convert a char array to ULONGLONG (C language)

Tags: c

I have an array of char and I need to convert it in a `ULONGLONG` to use it as a MAC address.
My array is like `"0X001234567890"` but they are all char so if I fit them in my `ULONGLONG` variable (using `unsigned long long` cast) they are all messed up.
Is there a way to have those characters in a `ULONGLONG` format to fit in the address variable?

My char array is formatted as 0 in [0], X in [1], 0 in [2], ecc..
And I build it after reading some values from a file.

```c
    char prefixAddr1[30] = "0X";
    char prefixAddr2[30] = "0X";
    int countAddr = 1;
    char addr[30] = "";
    char BTaddr1[30] = "";
    char BTaddr2[30] = "";
    FILE *fpAddress = fopen("BTaddr.txt", "r");
    while (fscanf(fpAddress, "%s", &addr) == 1){
            unsigned char *r, *w;
            for (w = r = addr; *r; r++){
                if (*r != ':'){
                    *w++ = *r;
                }
            }
            *w = '\0';
            if (countAddr == 1){
                strncpy(BTaddr1, addr, sizeof(addr));
            }
            else if (countAddr == 2){
                strncpy(BTaddr2, addr, sizeof(addr));
            }
            countAddr++;
        }
    strcat(prefixAddr1, BTaddr1);
    strcat(prefixAddr2, BTaddr2);
    printf("Address 1: %s\n", prefixAddr1);
    printf("Address 2: %s\n", prefixAddr2);
```

If I manually set my `ULONGLONG` variable and print the value with `%llu` I see the correct address.

```c
    typedef ULONGLONG BT_ADDR;
    BT_ADDR aSddr1 = 0X001343BD0F65;
    printf("Address 1: %llu\n", aSddr1);
```

I want my char array to have the same value as if I manually set the `aSddr1` variable.

From file I read `"00:12:34:56:78:90"`, clear the `":"` and append `"0X"` so my final string is `"0X001234567890"`. Everything in the first example is correct from my point of view. I only need to convert `prefixAddr1` in a way that my `BT_ADDR` variable will be work correctly as in the second example where the output is `0X001234567890`. At the moment if I do `(unsigned long long)prefixAddr1;` and print it I will print some random numbers.

Comment: Is it a string holding hex digits `"0x0012..."` or an array hoding `char arr[] = {0x00, 0x12, 0x34, ...}`? Please show your code including variable definitions, values you assign and what output you expect.

Comment: `char dst[100]; sprintf(dst, "Address 1: %llu\n", aSddr1);` .. or even `snprintf()`

Comment: You should check what content you are actually reading from your file.

Comment: `aSddr1 = strtoull("0X001343BD0F65", NULL, 16);` will set `aSddr1` to `0x1343bd0f65ull`.

Comment: @Gerhardh from file I read "00:12:34:56:78:90", clear the ":" and append "0X" so my final string is "0X001234567890". Everything in the first example is correct from my point of view. I only need to convert prefixAddr1 in a way that my BT_ADDR variable will be work correctly as in the second example where the output is 0X001234567890. At the moment if I do `(unsigned long long)prefixAddr1;`  and print it I will print some random numbers.

Comment: @IanAbbott I will try tomorrow when I will be back at work. Thanks.

Comment: Please add this important information to the question, not in comments.

Comment: @Gerhardh Sorry it's one of my first questions on StackOverflow. I edited the question.

Comment: Did you actually verify that you read that content from the file and after doing your  modifications, do you really have the expected content in your arrays? From your comment (and the update to the question) this only sounds like what you want to do, not like what you have verified.

Comment: @Gerhardh the array is good. I verified every step to check if I did not mess with some modification.

Comment: The solution from @IanAbbott works.